# How to remove product categories showing up at virtuemart's 2 search result page?

Tags: php, search, joomla, categories, virtuemart

I'm using the default Virtuemart product search module.
If I search for something, I'm redirected to a result page with my actual product results at the bottom, and the product categories on top...
I can't understand why this is happening, the categories showing up are useless. 
So, actually, I want to hide the product categories from my results page.
How can I do that? I can't find the view of the results page in order to change it.

I've searched everywhere but I can't seem to find it.

I'm using Joomla 2.5.4, and Virtuemart 2.0.6.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just figured it out.

On components/com_virtuemart/views/category/tmpl/default.php

replace line 72

```
if(!empty($this->category->children)){
```

with

```
if(!empty($this->category->children ) && !(boolean)JRequest::getVar('search', false)){
```

Answer (score 1):

I also found that this was also true clicking through my categories via my menu, so I added this to my category view override (seems to work ok so far):

```
if(!empty($this->category->children ) && !(boolean)JRequest::getVar('search', false) && empty($this->products)){
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to remove this product categories to show from the top of each page (manufacturer, search etc.) by simply un-tick the "Show Children Category" option in Virtuemart admin panel under Configuration/Templates. I'm using Joomla 2.5 and virtuemart 2.0.24.